# Django: Form values to redirect to url in single step

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I get values from a form, and redirect to a view called `MyView` like, `MyView/formvalue1/formvalue2` in single step ? I have a solution but I think its not the right way to do it.

In detail:

I am trying to use Django-ratings, as suggested in tutorial

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'rate-my-post/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<score>\d+)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
        'app_label': 'blogs',
        'model': 'post',
        'field_name': 'rating',
    }),
)
```

I have a VoteForm view, which renders VoteForm.html. In VoteForm.html What should be the form action? If I make it /rate-my-post/ then I cannot regex since, the url goes like `rate-my-post/?objectid=x&score=y`, then it cannot be regex'ed it since Django does not see the url after `?`.

My solution is:  I created another view called junk, the form sends to it now, and the junk view gets the form values, and then junk redirects a HttpResponseRedirect to rate-my-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the same view (and the same url) to render the form as you use to process the form (have a look at this example in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)). On successful processing of your form use a [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#reverse) to redirect to the page you need.

Something like -

```
def vote_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = VoteForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_view_name', 
                                                kwargs={'objectid':x, 'score': y}))
    else: # We're just rendering the html form
        form = VoteForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'vote.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```